Problema con un servicio de Java EE
Buenas tardes estoy tratando de implementar un servicio usando java EE, angular js apaartir de un stored procedure lo que pasa es que al momento de ejecutar mi proyecto los datos del servicio que estoy tratando de consumir me regresan null en la aplicacion queria saber que estoy haciendo mal o si estoy pasando algo por alto. Adjunto el codigo junto a una captura.
db.changelog
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION count_devices_android()
                RETURNS TABLE(android_version text, device_count bigint)
                LANGUAGE plpgsql
            AS $function$
            BEGIN
                RETURN QUERY
                WITH android_version AS (
                    SELECT
                        d.info::json->>'androidVersion' AS androidVersion,
                        COUNT(*) AS device_count
                    FROM devices d
                    WHERE d.info::json->>'androidVersion' IS NOT NULL
                    GROUP BY d.info::json->>'androidVersion'
                )
                SELECT * FROM android_version;
            END;
            $function$
 DeviceMapper           
 @Select("SELECT * FROM count_devices_android();")
    List<AndroidVersions> getAllAndroidVersions();
 DeviceDao
 public List<AndroidVersions> getAllAndroidVersions(){
        return this.mapper.getAllAndroidVersions();
    }
DeviceResource
@ApiOperation(
        value = "Get device android versions",
        notes = "Get all android versions"
    )
    @GET
    @Path("/AndroidVersions")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getAllAndroidVersions(){
        try{
            final List<AndroidVersions> androidVersions = this.deviceDAO.getAllAndroidVersions();
            return Response.OK(androidVersions);
        } catch(Exception e){
            log.error("Failed to retrieve the android versions for devices");
            return Response.INTERNAL_ERROR();
        }
    }
    device.controller.js
    $http.get('rest/private/devices/AndroidVersions').then(function (response){
                $scope.deviceData = device.androidVersion;
                $scope.deviceData = device.device_count;
                console.log(device.androidVersion);
            }).catch(function (error){
                console.Error('Error feting device data: ', error)
            });


